# Removing characters after a specified character format

Tags: sql, sql-server, numbers, character, field

I have a field that should contain 6 digits, a period, and six digits (######.######).  The application that I use allows this to be free-form entry.  Because users are users and will do what they want I have several fields that have a dash and some letters afterwards (######.######-XYZ).

Using T-SQL how do I identify and subsequently remove the -XYZ so that I can return the integrity of the data.  The column is an NVARCHAR(36), PK, and does not allow null values.  The column in question does have a unique columnID field.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? SQL Server has a bunch of functions which can help.

Comment: Nothing because I didn't know where to start.

Comment: You start by doing some research using similar questions and looking at the functions available to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since it'a free-form and "users are users", use `charindex` to find out if 1) there is a `-` and 2) remove it.

Example:

```
DECLARE @test NVARCHAR(36) = N'######.######-XYZ'
SELECT SUBSTRING(@test,1,COALESCE(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('-',@test,1),0),LEN(@test)+1)-1)
```

Comment: So then an update to the data looks to be straight forward with something like:
 update testtable
 set testcolumn = select SUBSTRING (testcolumn,1,coalesce(nullif(CHARINDEX('-',testcolumn,1),0),len(@test)+1)-1)
 where testcolumntype = 2

Answer (score 2):

If the part you want is the first 13 characters, then use `left()`:

```
select left(field, 13)
```

You can check if the first 13 characters are what you expect:

```
select (case when field like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
             then left(field, 13)
             else -- whatever you want when the field is bad
        end)
```

Comment: This was very helpful for identifying the incorrect records to submit for review.

Comment: @RonaldCarrell . . . Is there a reason you did not accept this answer?

Comment: @GordonLinoff your solution is fine if the user respect the format, but since Ronald state "users are users", that means that  it won't be necessarily be 13 characters long. one users could write  1234.1234  and another could write  01234.12340 , for exemple.

Comment: @MLeblanc . . . The question explicitly states:  "I have a field that should contain 6 digits, a period, and six digits (######.######).".